# Is it possible to port and compile a (obsolete) kernel module from an older kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, meta-raspberrypi

Is it possible to port and compile a kernel module from an older kernel?

The kernel module that I'm talking about here is BCM_WIMAX. It's been depreciated from "staging" on Linux kernel 3.18. Is it possible to port it to kernel 4.4?

3.18 - https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.18/drivers/staging/Kconfig

4.4 - https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.4/drivers/staging/Kconfig

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I'm currently on Raspbian and its latest release has 4.4 kernel. Is is possible to compile BCM_WIMAX for 4.4 kernel? Or does Pi 3 has a compatible image with BCM_WIMAX support?

I'm a newbie to Linux kernels and I apologize for not making my question clearer.

Comment: 1. Yes, it's possible. 2. Perhaps it takes not so many changes to be forward ported. In general, yes, should be not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any guide around on how to forward port a kernel module? I tried building the kernel (4.4) with BCM_WIMAX support using make config, but since the module's been removed from even staging it's nowhere to be found!

Comment: There is no guide, just a try and fail and try and fail process until it works